# Python 3.7 nested dataclass mypy type check error

Tags: typechecking, python-3.7, mypy, python-dataclasses

```
@dataclass
class A:
    one: int = 0
    two: str = ""


@nested_dataclass
class B:
    three: A
    four: str


@nested_dataclass
class C:
    five: B
    six: str


obj = C(five={"three":{"one": 23, "two":"narf"}, "four": "zort"}, six="fnord")

print(obj.five.three.two)
```

This code is correct according to functionality I guess. But, when I run `mypy src --ignore-missing-imports`, I get the following error:

```
run.py:50: error: Unexpected keyword argument "five" for "C"
run.py:50: error: Unexpected keyword argument "six" for "C"
```

Would be lot helpful if someone would help me overcome this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mypy has no idea what a `nested_dataclass` is -- it doesn't appear to be a decorator that's a standard part of the dataclasses module.

Consequently, mypy won't be able to understand whatever special logic is happening when you try instantiating C. As far as mypy is concerned, C is a regular old class -- and has no constructor.

The two possible solutions you have are to:

1. Just use `@dataclass` and drop whatever custom logic you're using.
2. Write a plugin for mypy that can understand the `@nested_dataclass` decorator. You can get some examples of what this looks like by looking at the dataclasses plugin that [comes baked into mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py).